# Session verifier giving access to the login action

Tags: tls, cookies

I have an web app that provides login page. User can use this login page while he has valid session verifier in cookie. Full flow looks like this:

1. User is redirected with some `code` in query param to login page
2. This `code` is validated by the server and if is valid then user gets a cookie with 32 cryptographically secure random bytes. This cookie isn't encrypted and even signed.
3. User can log in only if his session verifier is valid (server stores session hash)

My question is: If this cookie is `HttpOnly`, `Secure` and has `SameSite=Strict`, and `Path` setted to login page endpoint, is there any other attack possible except guessing these 32 bytes named as session verifier? If so, what and how can this be prevented and is it worth signing or encrypting these cookies, if they have high entropy?

This web app use HTTPS.

Comment: If you are using server sessions, this `code` is redundant...

Comment: I forgot to mention that this application is something like an OIDC. This code is needed to authorize the client.